# Attach log files in notification mail in jenkins pipeline workflow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to attach the content of some specific log files in mail body while nofifying a job execution failiure via email.

```
stage("Checkout Fusion Source")  {
    parallel 'A': {
        node('LinuxNode') {
            try {
                echo "Hello World(Linux)"
            } catch (Exception e) {
              mail body: 'Failed!',
              subject: 'Job has failed in Linux!',
              to: 'abc@xyz.com',
              attachmentsPattern: '/path/to/log/file/log_linux.out'
            }
            mail body: 'Passed!',
            subject: 'Job has passed in Linux!',
            to: 'abc@xyz.com',
            attachmentsPattern: '/path/to/log/file/log_linux.out'
        }
    }, 'B': {
         node('AixNode') {
            try {
                echo "Hello World(AIX)"
            } catch (Exception e) {
              mail body: 'Failed!',
              subject: 'Job has failed in AIX!',
              to: 'abc@xyz.com',
              attachmentsPattern: '/path/to/log/file/log_aix.out'
            }
            mail body: 'Passed!',
            subject: 'Job has passed in AIX!',
            to: 'abc@xyz.com',
            attachmentsPattern: '/path/to/log/file/log_aix.out'
        }
    }
}
```

This `attachmentsPattern` is not helping for the same.
P.S. My Jenkins version is `2.46.3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the email-extension plugin and try something like this in your pipeline workflow.

```
emailext attachLog: true, body: "${currentBuild.result}: ${BUILD_URL}", compressLog: true, replyTo: 'email@xxx.com',
       subject: "Build Notification: ${JOB_NAME}-Build# ${BUILD_NUMBER} ${currentBuild.result}", to: 'email123@xxx.com'
```